# Creating output file from input file but the strings are not printing correctly

Tags: c++, string, file-io, getline

The user inputs the amount they want to profit at the beginning and creates a .txt file for output. However the output is not giving the full string name of the game as seen down below.

Portion of code error is in I believe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

string gameName;
string blankLine;
double dollarAmount;
int costTicket, numPrize;
int prizeValue, totalTicket, notClaimed;
double remainTicket;
double remainTicketProfit;
double odds;


while( getline(fin >> ws, gameName)) 
{
        fin >> costTicket;     
        fin >> numPrize;       

        remainTicketProfit = 0;
        remainTicket = 0;

        for( int i = 0; i < numPrize; i ++)
        {
            fin >> prizeValue;  
            fin >> totalTicket; 
            fin >> notClaimed;  

            remainTicket =  remainTicket + notClaimed;

            if ( prizeValue > dollarAmount)
            {
                remainTicketProfit = remainTicketProfit + notClaimed;
            }
        }


        if(remainTicketProfit == 0)
        {
             myfile << left << setw(25) << gameName << setw(2) << "$" << setw(7) << costTicket << left << setw(17) << "Not possible" << endl;
        }

        else
        {

            odds = remainTicket / remainTicketProfit;

            myfile << left << setw(25) << gameName << setw(2) << "$" << setw(7) << costTicket  << "1 in " << fixed << setprecision(2) << odds << endl;
        }

        fin >> blankLine;
}
```

The input file text:

```
SMALL BEANS
1 5
10000 10 10
5000 50 8
100 100 6
10 1000 4
1 10000 2

PIRATE'S BOOTY, ARRR
10 6
50000 20 0
10000 100 0
1000 500 0
100 2000 738
10 7500 2945
1 10000 4476

BIG MONEY HU$TLA$
20 7
1000000 10 7
500000 50 29
10000 100 78
1000 500 396
100 2000 1439
20 5000 3218
10 10000 6210
```

And it's output file:

```
Game Cost Odds
-----------------------------------------------
SMALL BEANS $ 2 Not possible   
BOOTY, ARRR $ 5 Not possible   
MONEY HU$TLA$ $ 20 1 in 1625.29
```

As you can see the string gameName isn't fully appearing and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out:  `getline(fin >> ws, gameName`  -- I have never seen a `getline` call looking like this.  Where did you get this idea, and why not the traditional `getline(fin, gameName)`?

Comment: Before adding the " >> ws" it was creating white space before the next two string names, I added it just to see what it would do and it took away the whitespace

Comment: Also, if the issue is `gameName`, why not create a smaller program just to concentrate on reading and writing a string that contains a space?  The other items are not important.